# Colocar data em arquivo gerado pelo mysqldump

Tags: mysql, linux, data

Olá, quero colocar data no arquivo gerado pelo mysqldump, tenho um script shell que gera o dump, porem necessito colocar a data que foi gerado no nome do arquivo

Ex:
//tenho este comando

```
mysqldump -uroot -p12345 base_diversos > base_diversos.sql
```

é gerado o arquivo "base_diversos.sql sem problemas", necessito que o arquivo fique com data no nome:
Ex:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p12345 base_diversos > base_diversos_25_02_2015.sql
```

como colocar no script as variaveis de data para ficar dinamico e gerar com a data atual que esta sendo feito o backup?

seria algo como:
Ex:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p12345 base_diversos > base_diversos_%d_%m_%Y.sql
```

já tentei varias maneiras e da erro.

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por expansão do comando `date`:

```
base_diversos_$(date +%d_%m_%Y).sql
```

Na *man page* do `date` (`man date`) tem a lista dos formatos possíveis.

Comment: Funcionou certinho, tmb vi a documentação sobre a função tiha tudo lá mas não como vc descreveu. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -proot test_111 > "C:\Users\USER_2\Desktop\backup folder\test_111_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.sql"